# Get cookie from URL

Tags: go, url, cookies

I am wondering if there is a way to get a cookie from a URL using golang? I have tried to use a few examples that come up when I google it but it never seems to return the cookie

Comment: Cookies are not part of the URL. Cookies are sent in request and response headers. The http.Request and http.Response types have Cookies methods for reading them.

Comment: Ok so how would you recommend going about using those to get the cookie?

Comment: See https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.Cookies and https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.Cookies

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
package http
import "net/http"

func get_cookie(ref, name string) (*http.Cookie, error) {
   res, err := http.Get(ref)
   if err != nil {
      return nil, err
   }
   defer res.Body.Close()
   for _, cook := range res.Cookies() {
      if cook.Name == name {
         return cook, nil
      }
   }
   return nil, http.ErrNoCookie
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.